# Is it possible to call a Javascript function after an update in Primefaces version before 6?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I noticed that, even with `oncomplete`, on my old version of PrimeFaces, the JS is called immediately, without waiting the re-rendering of the page or of a component. As a workaround, I use he ugly `setTimeout`.

Is there some other trick to circumvent this old behavior? PrimeFaces has some JS extension for this?

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.7

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @MisterJojo welcome to you. I'll post a minimal example as soon as I have time :). In the meanwhile, can you see if you can reproduce the problem? Thank you a lot. If you don't have JSF, don't mind and skip this question.

Comment: @MisterJojo in the meanwhile, can you please remove the close vote? I'll post all the info, but if you close the question, I can't :-)

Comment: `oncomplete` should only execute when an AJAX call is returned and components are updated.  Its possible its a bug wiht your PF 3.4  version but I know for a fact is does not happen in 6, 7, 8, 10 versions of PrimeFaces as we do this all the time.

Comment: No need to add an example. The question is clear (only the version was missing). You should not have tagged it with JavaScript. It is not answerable by Javascript experts. And it might trigger responses like the one above from people who don't know JSF.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue was fixed in PF 6.2 and OP is using PF 3.4.

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2742

Comment: Thank you Melloware, but, as you know, I'm stuck with 3.4.1. Any workaround?

Comment: Not wanting to invest in upgrading is not being stuck, it's a choice, and it's up to you. You can always backport all the fixes of bugs you run into in a fork of PrimeFaces 3.4.1, but that would take way more time IMO. In this case you could patch some JavaScript. Have a look at the commit fixing the linked issue.